# Get current user in SPFeatureReceiver?

Tags: user, user-accounts, feature-receiver

I am working on a web application-scoped feature which creates a site collection. I would like to set the person who activated the feature as site collection owner. To do that, I would have to either:

- find out who started the featurereceiver
- find out who the current user is inside the featurereceiver

For obvious reasons, I can't rely on SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.

Comment: Isn't the person who started the featurereceiver and the current user inside the featurereceiver the same person? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work, but I would try this:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    //Get webapplication
    SPWebApplication webApplication = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
    //Get current user from any sitecollection and rootweb
    SPUser user = webApplication.Sites[0].RootWeb.CurrentUser;
    //Custom code
 }
```

Since you need the current user, it does not matter where you get it from, so I use an existing sitecollection's rootweb and get the current user from there...